# How to import the OWL classes as a Node in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, owl, linked-data

I am working on Neo4j, and I imported my ontology, but I didn't understand how Neo4j import the class owl:NamedIndividual or the other class other than owl:Class, because it gives me just one node label which is Resource, there aren't any way to import this owl:NamedIndividual as a separate Node with different label ?
this is a part of my ontology

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ss/ontologies/2018/6/DAO#SideCollision">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ss/ontologies/2018/6/DAO#Hazard"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

and this what Neo4j gives me
[image]